# Assign two variables for a checkbox C# Windows Phone 8.1 (Custom Checkbox)

Tags: c#, xaml, checkbox, windows-phone-8.1

i got a list of `checkbox`, but i need to pick 2 values, not just the "Content" value, i need a `string` and a `float` value, on just one `checkbox`.

In C# winforms, i can do this using:

```
public CheckBoxCustom : System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox 
{
    String thing { get; set; }
    float price { get; set; }
}
```

and create a new control that receive 2 values, So on C# xaml win phone 8.1 this is not the way to create the control, any tips?

SOLVED!

Code:

```
        Dictionary<string, float> dicionario = new Dictionary<string, float>();

        foreach (CheckBox c in checkboxes)
        {
            if (c.IsChecked == true)
            {
                string pedido = c.Content.ToString();
                float valor = float.Parse(c.Tag.ToString());
                dicionario.Add(pedido, valor);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Tag property with the "concrete" object instance, class derivation is used for other things not generic containment.  One lesson that I generally find from reading the documentation is that a lot of thougth was spent in common usage... read the docs and samples

Comment: Tag property helped this time, we don't need to use more than 2 values, but if we have to use 3 values, we will have problems, but this helped a lot, i did it and is working perfectly, Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for this late response..TAG is an aggregation construct that allows you to bind any structure for a later context